# Move Windows 10 folders to another disk to free up space

Tags: windows, disk-space

I have a 60GB SSD that is near full and Windows is having trouble installing updates.
I feel like I picked all the low hanging fruit ages ago; documents, programs and pretty much anything that is not Windows related is already installed on another drive. I have cleaned up old Windows installations

The biggest culprits are Windows and the AppData folder. Windows and User folders take up about 50GB.
[image: Disk]

I've thought about moving the User folder to another disk but multiple sources tell me this is a bad idea.
What is a safe way to free up disk space without too much headache?

Also, I don't see Windows/Installer in my File Explorer even with hidden folders visible. I can still navigate to it via the address bar. I vaguely remember having moved this in the past with `mklink` to another drive but maybe that never happened or got undone somehow? Could something like `mklink` be a viable solution to this problem (and how)?

Comment: Have you moved your page file and hibernation file (if you have one)?

Comment: @spikey_richie Yes, those are already on another drive

Comment: mklink is indeed going to be the way to go. You can move appdata this way, but it will break when upgrading your windows 10 install, so you have to do it every time you get one of those big windows 10 updates. Also, you cannot have appdata being in use, so you must either do this outside of windows, or from another user and not have the main user being logged in.

Comment: @LPChip how will it break? What if the total space exceeds the disk space on my SSD?

Comment: Whatever you'll do, this SSD is just too small and you'll run out of space again in at most a few months.

Comment: @gronostaj So buying a bigger SSD, clone my C drive and make that the C drive. Could be viable. Would that be much hassle/risky?

Comment: @Jonathan assuming your SSD is actually removable it is not that risky at all. Out of preference you need a USB enclosure for the one you are copying to, but if you have that then it is simply using Macrium Reflect, Clonezilla or another of the partitioning tools to clone the old disk to the new one and then simply swapping out the old. I've done it a few times at least with no problem.

Comment: @Mokubai Cool, seems like the way to go.

Comment: Though SSDs are faster than HDDs, I advice you to buy an HDD instead, because with the same cost, you can get an HDD with more storage space than an SSD.

Comment: @Jonathan the only thing to make sure of while cloning is that you are actually enlarging the main partition when you do it. Most tools give you a visual indication and you can change settings such as shuffling a partition to the end and enlarging another before doing the actual clone.

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς HDDs are only a good idea if you **must** have a lot of storage. If you can accept a drop in storage then I would choose an SSD absolutely every time simply for the fact that you don't spend 10 minutes waiting for the machine to boot and another 10 to load any large application. In a laptop a 2.5" HDD is essentially a death sentence to any productivity you might have had. I've had identical laptops with 1TB HDDs and 128GB SSDs and I would chose the SSD *every time* and put the HDD in a USB enclosure.

Comment: The link could be replaced by a new AppData folder. Its not guaranteed to happen, but it may. You first MOVE the data to the other disk, so its no longer on the SSD, then with mklink you make a redirection, a tunnel.

Comment: Moving AppData can cause problems.